# How these two product came in $x^n-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have some confusion regarding Dummit and foote Book Algebra, page number $554$

It is written that

> $$x^n-1 = \prod_{\substack{\zeta \in \mu_n}} \left(x -\zeta \right)= \prod_{\substack{d|n}} \prod_{\substack{\zeta \in \mu_d}  \zeta \text{ is primitive}} \left(x -\zeta \right)$$

**My question** : Im not  getting How these  two product came  ? I means $\prod_{\substack{d\mid n}} \prod_{\substack{\zeta \in \mu_d}}$  in $x^n-1$ ?

**My thinking** :I know that here  $\zeta = e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{n}}$ and $\mu_n = \mathbb{Z}_n$.

$\{1,2,...,(n-1)\} \in \mathbb{Z_n}$

$$x^n-1 = \prod_{\substack{\zeta \in\mathbb{Z}_n }} \left(x -e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{n}} \right)$$

$$x^n-1 = \prod_{\substack{(n-1)! }} \left(x -e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{n}} \right)$$

since  $1\times 2\times\cdots\times n-1=(n-1)!$

Comment: $\mu_n$ is not equal to the integers modulo $n$, it is only **isomorphic** to it. $\mu_n$ is the multiplicative group of $n$th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. The second product is incorrect, though, since the second multiplication should only be over the **primitive** $d$th roots of unity, not over all roots of unity.

Comment: ok@ArturoMagidin i edited

Comment: The answer should now be obvious: an $n$th root of unity is a primitive $d$th root of unity if and only if its multiplicative order is $d$, in which case it lies in $\mu_d$ for some $d|n$.

Comment: And your second derivation is an absolute mess; how do you get $(n-1)!$? Are you under the impression that every integer less than $n$ divides $n$, and that $n$ does not divide $n$?

Comment: im sorry for that @ArturoMagidin  Actually ,I misunderstood the $\zeta \in \mu_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand that $x^n-1= \prod (x- \zeta)$, where $\zeta$ varies over *all* of the $n$th roots of unity, right?  And any $n$th root of unity is a *primitive* $d$th root of unit of unity for some unique $d$, where $d \mid n$.

So all we're doing is collecting the roots that are primitive $d$th roots of unity for the same $d$, and then taking the product over all $d$ such that $d \mid n$.  This product will pick up *all* of the $n$th roots of unity and each specific root will occur exactly once.  The multiplicative group of the primitive $d$th roots of unity is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $U_d$ of units of the ring $\Bbb Z / d \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ok ,that  mean $\zeta \in \mu_n \implies \zeta^n=1 $.Am i right ?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, $\zeta \in \mu_n \Rightarrow \vert \zeta \vert = n$, which is a slightly stronger result, because for the non-primitive $n$th roots of unity $\zeta$, we have only that $\vert \zeta \vert \mid n$.